# Get php stylesheet output and store as variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the output of a php file and store that content into a variable on a separate page. The content type in the php stylesheet is text/css. When i'm able to store that content into a variable, I will use it with a jQuery plugin text editor so users can edit the dynamic stylesheet.

Here's what I have going to so far.

**Php stylesheet example**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css");
$value1 = 5;
?>
.example {
    top: <?= $value1 ?>px;
}
More css...
```

**Second file example**

```
function includeToVar($f){
    ob_start();
    require($f);
    return ob_get_clean();
}

$content = includeToVar("file/path/file.php");
```

**Desired output**

```
.example {
    top: 5px;
}
```

**The issue**

The issue i'm currently facing is that when I store the content into the variable $content, the content-type of the second page changes to text/css. This is not what I want. I want the second page to stay as text/html.

How I can I prevent the second page from changing content types? Is there a better way to store this content?

Comment: If you want to use variables in CSS, why not look into something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-Type: text/css");
```

Just don't use this line, you only want the content right?
The header will be set for the entire run not what you include.
I don't believe you can actually set headers in a variable ;)

What else you could do is read the file instead of including it so you could eval() the content's of the file, but I don't really want to recommend you to do this.